# Node Outside of openshift cluster can't access pods inside cluster

Tags: openshift, iptables, sdn

Note I have three nodes (A, B, C) whose ips are `172.18.143.115, 172.18.143.117, 172.18.143.124`.

A and B are a openshift cluster using ovs-sdn as its network pulgin, pod network is `10.130.0.0/16`, service ip range is `172.30.0.0/16`. there is a pod P(`10.130.3.249:8002`) in node B, and a corresponding
service S(`172.30.148.77:8002`).

I can curl S in node A or B, but can't do it in node C
So I add a route like if dst_ip is P then goto node A or B. 
Then strange things happen, if the route points to B, I can curl S, otherwise if
the route points to A, I can't curl S.

Through tcpdump, i find pod P return a TCP ACK packet to node C through its veth,
then this packet is output to tun0 according to flows in OVS, according to route it should be send by ens192(network interface) since its dst_ip is node C, but i can't catch it on ens192 with tcpdump, it seems like that this packet is droped. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic is only routed within the cluster by default, so if the application on C is not part of the cluster, then ingress and egress won't be possible between the A/B nodes and C. This is all controlled by application's service configuration.

To route ingress and egress traffic from/to outside the cluster, you'll need to configure the service of your application. One of the easier ways to do this is to use the type [LoadBalancer](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_load_balancer.html#automatically-assign-create-lb) service.

You can also use the type [NodePort](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html#configuring-the-service) service, which will expose the service on a mapped port in the range of 30000 - 32767 across all nodes.

Lastly, you can assign an [External IP](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_service.html#manually-assign-ip-service) to the service to allow outside traffic into the cluster.

Hope this helps!

Comment: We found that this is because of there is no conntrack of pod P and node C on node C, so the packet is dropped. Thank you all the same